# How to bind method to component Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I use child component in template:

```
  <slide-panel
    (swipeleft)="onSwipeLeft($event)"
    (swiperight)="onSwipeRight($event)"
    [activePane]="isLeftVisible ? 'left' : 'right'">
</slide-panel>
```

As you can see I use input `activePane` and pass inside variable `isLeftVisible` from parent component.

This variable is changed by:

```
 public onSwipeLeft(event: any) {
    this.isLeftVisible = true;
  }

  public onSwipeRight(event: any) {
    this.isLeftVisible = false;
  }
```

I want to make this component isolated and move all functions onSwipeLeft, onSwipeRight inside.

Now child component depends from parent variable `isLeftVisible`.

So, and everywhere where I use this component I should create `isLeftVisible`.

Could I bind `(swipeleft)="onSwipeLeft($event)"` but move handler `onSwipeLeft` inside component?

Comment: what about create component - wrapper for slide-panel component, which just add function which you need and call slide-panel component ?

Comment: If the slide-panel is your own component you can just edit it so that instead of emitting the swipeleft/swiperight you do the action to show/hide the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[EventEmitter][1]`

You can do this in child:

```
@Output() open: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

//in the method that creates the events you do

this.open.emit(//your parameters);
```

and in your father you do

```
<.... (open)="handleopenEvent(e)" ....>
```

and in father .ts you do :

```
public handleopenEvent(any:e){}
```